# Making a JS toggle div close when another is opened, and change image on click

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I am new to JavaScript. Currently, I am working on a small toggle for my website.

The goal is to have three buttons that open up different sections with information. I have this working on my website. Now, what I want to achieve is to make other divs close when the others are opened up. Furthermore, I would like the first div to be open when the page is loaded, including an indicator (for example orange image) on the button. Can you please help me with this?

For some reason, the script works on my website, but not on the JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/q7evaLsn/1/

Current code:

```js
 
$('.button1').click(function(){
    $('.product').slideToggle('slow');   
});

$('.button2').click(function(){
    $('.lockedin').slideToggle('slow');   
});

$('.button3').click(function(){
    $('.developers').slideToggle('slow');   
});
```

```css
.button2
{
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.button3
{
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h3>
    <img src="http://www.mindaffect.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/product-holder.png" class="button1" alt="Expand"/> 
</h3>
<h3>
    <img src="http://www.mindaffect.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/lockedin-holder.png" class="button2" alt="Expand"/> 
</h3>
<h3>
    <img src="http://www.mindaffect.nl/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/developers-holder.png" class="button3" alt="Expand"/> 
</h3>

<div class="product">
    Testdiv1
</div>

<div class="lockedin">
    Testdiv2
</div>

<div class="developers">
    Testdiv3
</div>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply slide up everything before you start toggling.

For ex

```
   $('.button3').click(function(){
     $('.product').slideUp();
     $('.lockedin').slideUp();
     $('.developers').slideToggle('slow');   
   });
```

Comment: That is a really easy fix for the start, thanks a bunch! Do you also know how I can show a different image when a div button is active?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSfiddle isn't working because you haven't included the jQuery library required for some of your functions. For future reference, jQuery is a popular javascript library which simplifies and extends some basic javascript functions, you can use both interchangeably however if you do want the extra features of jQuery then you'll have to include it like so in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

As mentioned by @SURESH you'll likely want to slide the other areas up where you are toggling the target area:

```
$('.example-button').click(function(){
  $('.section-to-hide-1').slideUp();
  $('.section-to-hide-2').slideUp();
  $('.section-to-toggle-1').slideToggle();
});
```

Just as further formatting advice, you have your images (that are acting as buttons) within  header tags.

- It's generally bad practice to use these header tags for anything
  other than headings/titles
- I'd recommend using A tags or even BUTTON tags to do the same job
- I'd try not to use IMG tags as essentially text buttons, you will be able to style a button similarly like so:

  ```
  <button class="button1">Products</button>

  <style>
    .button1 { text-align: center; padding: 10px; text-transform: uppercase: border-radius: 100%; border: 3px solid orange; background: white; color: #000;  }
  </style>
  ```

This will allow search engines/screen readers to read your button element, and you can make hover effects etc.